# dojo nested Custom Widget undefined not a function

Tags: dojo, widget, nested

I've a Widget called `stat.widget.Weekly` that is a `_Container` and it `require`'s `stat.widget.Daily` as `Daily` But Whenever I use `new Daily()` I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

My Code goes like this

```
require([
 "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/parser", ..., "stat/widget/Daily", "dijit/_Container"
 ], function(declare, ... , _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, Daily, _Container){
     declare("stat.widget.Weekly", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _Container], {
        ....
        update: function(){
            new Daily();//< Fires Error
        },
        postCreate: function(){
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function(){
              self.update();
            }, 500);            
        }
     });
 });
```

But this `stat/widget/Daily` can be be instantiated in console with `new`

Answer (score 0):

If your stat.widget.Weekly is placed in a file under stat-Modulepath/widget/Daily.js, this syntax would be more smooth to process in the classloader:

```
define([ // using define instead of require
 "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/parser", ..., "stat/widget/Daily", "dijit/_Container"
 ], function(declare, ... , _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, Daily, _Container){

 var myPrivates = declare("stat.widget._WeeklyResource", [], {
     ...
 });
 var myDefinition = declare("stat.widget.Weekly", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _Container], {
     ...
 });
 // returning the definition
 return myDefinition;
```

});